# How to use WIX Domain, to be specific how to create a route for the domain

Tags: subdomain, web-development-server, velo

I have access to a Wix domain, let's say *[www.example.fit](http://www.example.fit)*, I want to create a "*[www.example.fit/something*"](http://www.example.fit/something*%22).
Is there any way I can develop the backend for this separately on my own ide using the language I want.
If that is not possible is there a way to using the Wix Dashboard/UI for doing the same if so, how? and does Wix allow me to develop this on their Ui using my preferred libraries/language?

I have tried googling about this and reading the Wix docs, but I am not able to understand how to go about it as it doesn't seem clear.